# System.Text.Json JsonConverter String array to single string

Tags: c#, json, converters, system.text.json, jsonconverter

I would like to convert the following JSON. As you can see, the array has a single entry. I would like to convert it into a simple string.

```
{
    "@timestamp": [
        "2022-05-24T01:53:32.600Z"
    ],
    "site.siteCode": [
        "ZAR"
    ],
    "username": [
        "QR02159T1"
    ]
}
```

I tried to create a `JsonConverter` with *System.Text.Json* but it never call despite adding in the converter.

My Converter:

```cs
public class ArrayToSingleConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            // Proper array, we can deserialize from this token onwards.
            // return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(ref reader, options);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The model:

```cs
public class Ad4p 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("site.siteCode")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToSingleConverter))]
    public string Sitecode { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("username")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToSingleConverter))]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("@timestamp")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToSingleConverter))]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The implementation:

```cs
_jsonOptions.Converters.Add(new ArrayOrObjectJsonConverter<string>());
var ad4pList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Ad4p>(json, _jsonOptions);
```

But I have the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Text.Json.dll: 'The converter specified on 'CrawlerPowerBi.Models.Ad4p.Sitecode' is not compatible with the type 'System.String'.'

How to convert an array of strings or objects into a single string or object?
Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you need to override CanConvert for your JsonConverter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.canconvert?view=net-6.0. Has ArrayOrObjectJsonConverter you register anything todo with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some attempts and referring to a similar example [Support round trip for Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#support-round-trip-for-stackt),

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions _jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
var ad4pList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Ad4p>(json, _jsonOptions);
```

```cs
public class ArrayToSingleConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{

    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        
        reader.Read();
        
        while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
        {
            list.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(ref reader, options));

            reader.Read();
        }
        
        return list.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Supported generic

```
public class ArrayToSingleConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{

    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        
        reader.Read();
        
        while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
        {
            list.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options));

            reader.Read();
        }
        
        return list.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Ad4p
{
    [JsonPropertyName("site.siteCode")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToSingleConverter<string>))]
    public string Sitecode { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("username")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToSingleConverter<string>))]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("@timestamp")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToSingleConverter<string>))]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

[Demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BSt7a7)

---

Alternative:

```cs
reader.Read();
        
while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
{
    list.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options));

    reader.Read();
}
```

can be replaced with:

```cs
while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
{
    list.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options));
}
```

As both aimed to read the JSON value until `EndArray` was found.

[Demo on .NET Fiddle (Alternative)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ac8Zn2)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I succeedeed with Newtonsoft but I prefer native code. So your solution is the best.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to automatically convert the string array to a single string using a custom JSON converter in C#, you can create a custom converter class that inherits from `JsonConverter` provided by the Newtonsoft.Json library. Here's an example:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

public class StringArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private string _delimiter = " ; ";
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string[]);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
              string[] arrayString = token.ToObject<string[]>();

              return string.Join(_delimiter, arrayString);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is string[] stringArray)
        {
            string convertedString = string.Join(", ", stringArray);
            writer.WriteValue(convertedString);
        }
    }
}

// Define the class representing your JSON object
public class MyJsonObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringArrayConverter))]
    public string[] Data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Example JSON object
        string json = @"{
            ""data"": [""string1"", ""string2"", ""string3""]
        }";

        // Deserialize the JSON object
        MyJsonObject jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJsonObject>(json);

        // Access the data property
        string dataArray = jsonObject.Data;

        // Convert the array to a string
        string convertedString = dataArray;  // The converter automatically converted the array to a string

        Console.WriteLine(convertedString);
    }
}
```

In this example, the `StringArrayConverter` class is a custom converter that handles the conversion of the string array to a string and vice versa.

The `CanConvert` method checks if the `objectType` is a string array. The `ReadJson` method is responsible for deserializing the JSON array into a string array. The `WriteJson` method converts the string array to a single string before writing it as JSON.

In the `MyJsonObject` class, the `Data` property is annotated with the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringArrayConverter))]` attribute to apply the custom converter.

When you deserialize the JSON object using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, the string array is automatically converted to a single string during the deserialization process.

In the `Main` method, `dataArray` is an array of strings, but `convertedString` is automatically assigned the concatenated string value due to the custom converter.

Ensure that you have the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package installed in your project for this code to work.

Not: This is ChatGPT answer and it solves my problem. I made a little bit change to work properly.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Yes it is. Is it forbidden to share chatGPT answer here?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned - A lot of people were/are bulk posting answers that they haven't verified. It's good that you've been able to verify this one, but it's a fairly blanket policy because it was being misused